# Word for a person who speaks bad about person 1 in front of person 2 and vice versa

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call Person A who speaks bad about Person B to Person C and speaks bad about Person C to Person B?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the word for saying bad words about other people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177129/what-is-the-word-for-saying-bad-words-about-other-people)

Comment: Is Person A trying to play B and C off against each other?

Comment: _Two-faced_ almost works. According to _yourdictionary_: "An example of someone who would be described as two-faced is a person who pretends to be your friend and then starts calling you names as soon as you leave the room." https://www.yourdictionary.com/two-faced